# Stop shared library linking dropping unused classes

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, shared-libraries

I've found lots of questions on the opposite question of eliminating dead code, but I cannot find an answer to this:

Given a class hierarchy like:

```
BaseView
 +- Base2DView
     +- Concrete2DView
         +- Specialised2DView
```

I link all the files together into `view_classes.a`, then I add in code that instantiates `Concrete2DView` and make a `view_renderer.so`. Next, I create another library `specialised_view_renderer.so` that instantiates `Specialised2DView` and lists `view_renderer.so` as a dependency.

However, the process of generating `view_renderer.so` has eliminated the `Specialised2DView.cpp.o` file as unused code, as nothing turns up when I use `nm view_renderer.so`.

I know that either linking against `view_classes.a` or moving `Specialised2DView.cpp` to the `specialised_view_renderer.so` project would fix this, but this is legacy third-party code that I probably shouldn't fiddle with too much.

So, is there an easy way to mark `Specialised2DView.cpp.o` or the class within as not to be eliminated when building the `view_renderer.so`? Bonus points if there is an option for a standard `cmake` `target_link_libraries()` line.

Comment: [CMP0063](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0063.html) seems relevant, as it mentions "However, some sources may be compiled as part of static libraries or object libraries and then linked into a shared library later." which is your use case. You may also need to set the `CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET` property (or the global `CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET`) on your static library to `default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there an easy way to mark Specialised2DView.cpp.o or the class within as not to be eliminated when building the view_renderer.so?

Yes:

```
g++ -shared -o view_renderer.so ... \
  -Wl,--whole-archive view_classes.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

To understand why this is happening, and why the solution works, you need to know the rules which linkers use to select which objects to include in the link. A good description is [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

Answer (score 0):

What the solution I arrived at was as follows. Before I had:

```
BaseView
 +-- virtual void foo() = 0;
 +- Base2DView
     +-- virtual void foo() {...}
     +- Concrete2DView
         +-- virtual void foo() {...}
         +- Specialised2DView
             +-- void bar() {foo();}
```

If I changed the leaf call to:

```
             +-- void bar() {Concrete2DView::foo();}
```

The code linked and ran problem-free.